# single line for statement: %%i 'unexpected at this time'

Tags: for-loop, cmd

```
for /r %%i in (*) do (echo %%i)
```

Results in

> %%i was unexpected at this time

Why?

Comment: Isn't it `%i` inside the actual `for`? Like as the parameter for the `echo`.

Comment: From within a batch that works fine for me, is there any other code in the file?

Comment: % for command line, %% for batch file.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You must be trying to run the command from the command line and not from within a batch file. Use a single % instead of two when running from the command line.

```
for /r %i in (*) do (echo %i)
```

Type `HELP FOR` from the command line and read the 3rd paragraph.

Comment: If you see "I was unexpected at this time", read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509652 before cutting-and-pasting this answer into your file.

Answer (score 1):

One % when you need to test in direct. Double %% when you run it by script.

Answer (score 0):

If Anyone is wondering how to extract the data to a file

*using CMD*

All files

```
for /r %i  in (*) do @echo %~ni >> AllFiles.txt
```

For a specific extension

```
for /r %i  in (*.mp3) do @echo %~ni >> songs.txt
```

File name with extension

```
for /r %a in (*) do @echo %~nxa >> FileNameWithExtension.txt
```

**Note**:
If you're making a batch script use "%%" instead of every "%" mentioned above

Answer (score -1):

Syntax:

```
FOR /R [[drive:]path] %%parameter IN (set) DO command
```

Need the path before %%i... which is why it's `Unexpected`

If you want to do `*` for current directory, just use ".\" for the path

```
for /r ".\" %%i in (*) do (echo %%i)
```

Comment: The path is **NOT** required after the /r option. It defaults to the current directory.

Comment: meh... user specified batch-file and that's the only thing I saw missing. So it's a PEBKAC issue =/