# What is the difference between % and %% in a cmd file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I recently included a line similar to this in a .cmd file:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b .\directory\*.sql') DO sqlcmd -b -o ".\directory\output\%%f.txt" -i ".\directory\%%f"
```

Originally I had only used %f, and it would work fine when run on the command line, but not when run through the file.  When I switched to %%f, it worked in the file.  Just wondering what the difference is.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

*(Explanation in more details can be found in [an archived Microsoft KB article](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/075/Q75634/).)*

Three things to know:

1. The percent sign is used in batch files to represent command line parameters: `%1`, `%2`, ...
2. Two percent signs with any characters in between them are interpreted as a variable:

   `echo %myvar%`
3. Two percent signs *without* anything in between (in a batch file) are treated like a single percent sign in a command (not a batch file): `%%f`

---

Why's that?

For example, if we execute your (simplified) command line

```
FOR /f %f in ('dir /b .') DO somecommand %f
```

in a batch file, *rule 2* would try to interpret

```
%f in ('dir /b .') DO somecommand %
```

as a variable. In order to prevent that, you have to apply *rule 3* and escape the `%` with an second `%`:

```
FOR /f %%f in ('dir /b .') DO somecommand %%f
```

Comment: Is there an explanation for why I can get away with using just one percent sign in a FOR loop, when executed directly from a command prompt, and not from a batch file? I know about the DOS heritage, but we **can** use variables from a command line now.

Comment: Also, make sure the variable is a single character.

Comment: What if I want to issue command which has % in it e.g.: for /f %%i in ('git log -1 --pretty=format:"%%H"') do set GIT_COMMIT=%%i

Comment: In addition to %G in a for loop, %1 is also allowed. %% is needed in a script to avoid ambiguities. "When working at the command line (not in a batch script) there is no possibility of any batch file parameters %1, %2 etc so the logic above is not followed and hence FOR parameters on the command line only need a single %." See [details](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-percent.html).

Answer (score 20):

In DOS you couldn't use environment variables on the command line, only in batch files, where they used the `%` sign as a delimiter. If you wanted a literal `%` sign in a batch file, e.g. in an `echo` statement, you needed to double it.

This carried over to Windows NT which allowed environment variables on the command line, however for backwards compatibility you still need to double your `%` signs in a .cmd file.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very understandable. `%%` in batch acted like `\\ ` in bash.  Where one would need to cancel the meaning of the previous percent-sign in a batch file; because variables in batch look like `%var%`. So because percent had a special meaning you needed to use `%%var%%` so a variable was still usable in a batch file.