# fsutil command not working inside batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am having the below command working in cmd in windows 7 to create 40 thousand files on the go, but not executing while I try to write it as a batch file. I copy pasted the same cmd as a file  40k.bat along with other commands.

```
For /L %i in (1,1,40000) do fsutil createnew 40kfile%i.txt 1048
```

Please let me know why fsutil not working when I execute it as batch file. Or please point me to any other alternative which is as fast as fsutil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `%i` with `%%i` everywhere, when you execute it in a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be more like this:

```
For /L %%i in (1,1,40000) do fsutil createnew 40kfile%%i.txt 1048
```

You need double %. Take a look at this http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php it should show you about the `%%`

I also fould some infomation here [What is the difference between % and %% in a cmd file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509652/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-a-cmd-file) You may find this useful.