# Windows Batch script - what does %%i mean?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I wrote (using knowledge from Internet) script (batch file) to remove all folders and files inside a folder.

```
DEL /F /Q /S C:\commonfiles\*
for /D %%i in ("C:\commonfiles\*") do RD /S /Q "%%i"
```

I just don't know what %%i means. Is it like i++ in C++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14510117/3496666

Answer (score 10):

`%%i` is simply the loop variable. This is explained in the documentation for the `for` command, which you can get by typing `for /?` at the command prompt.

The fact that a double percent sign is used in a batch file is discussed in these links:

- [What is the difference between % and %% in a cmd file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509652/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-a-cmd-file)
- https://superuser.com/questions/670992/what-does-the-percent-sign-and-in-a-batch-file-argument-mean

Answer (score 1):

In this case `FOR /D` iterates trough all directories in `C:\commonfiles\` and on each iteration the current directory is accessible with %%i variable. It's a special variable that is valid only in FOR command context. In command prompt you'll need to use:

`for /D %i in ("C:\commonfiles\*") do RD /S /Q "%i"`

For more info `FOR /?` or [SS64.COM](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)