# Offline Backup script for DB2

Tags: db2, backup, database-backups

I am trying to do a offline backup for my DB2(10.1.0) using script and schedule it.

db2backup.bat

```
@ECHO OFF 
FOR xxxx IN (OPNACT BLOGS SNCOMM DOGEAR FILES FORUM HOMEPAGE PEOPLEDB WIKIS) DO ( 
 DB2 CONNECT TO xxxx 
 DB2 QUIESCE DATABASE IMMEDIATE FORCE CONNECTIONS 
 DB2 CONNECT RESET 
 DB2 BACKUP DATABASE xxxx TO "C:\Backup\DB2" WITH 2 BUFFERS BUFFER 1024 PARALLELISM 3 WITHOUT PROMPTING 
 DB2 CONNECT TO xxxx 
 DB2 UNQUIESCE DATABASE 
 DB2 CONNECT RESET 
)
```

But when i try to run it,

```
DB2CMD /c /w /i C:\Backup\db2backup.bat
```

I am getting a error ,

"xxxx was unexpected at this time."

so why i am getting this?how can i avoid it ?

Many Thanks for your input !!.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the how you deal with the variable. xxxxx is not a valid name, it should be preceded by two percentages: %%xxxxx

```
@ECHO OFF 
FOR %%xxxx IN (OPNACT BLOGS SNCOMM DOGEAR FILES FORUM HOMEPAGE PEOPLEDB WIKIS) DO ( 
 DB2 CONNECT TO %%xxxx 
 DB2 QUIESCE DATABASE IMMEDIATE FORCE CONNECTIONS 
 DB2 CONNECT RESET 
 DB2 BACKUP DATABASE %%xxxx TO "C:\Backup\DB2" WITH 2 BUFFERS BUFFER 1024 PARALLELISM 3 WITHOUT PROMPTING 
 DB2 CONNECT TO %%xxxx 
 DB2 UNQUIESCE DATABASE 
 DB2 CONNECT RESET 
)
```

For more information you can check this question [What is the difference between % and %% in a cmd file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509652/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-a-cmd-file)

Comment: hi AngocA , i try like this too , but i get same error saying ->  %xxxx was unexpected at this time.

Comment: This is not a DB2 error, but a batch problem. Have you tried with just one 'x': FOR %%x IN (OPNACT BLOGS SNCOMM DOGEAR FILES FORUM HOMEPAGE PEOPLEDB WIKIS) DO (echo %%x) Once it shows the values with the echo command, you can replace that with the db2 commands.