# Get file info from file path in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a document table in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database with a structure like this:

```
id | date_created | file_path             | file_type
---+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------
1  | 2016-11-14   | \\server\docs\123.doc | application/msword
2  | 2016-11-15   | \\server\imgs\456.png | image/png
```

I need to determine the file size of a subset of documents. So I have a query that will select certain rows from the document table (based on their ID) and I would need to find out what the total file size is of that set of documents. I did some Googling (before coming here of course) but most things I can find related to files/SQL is about log file sizes which is obviously NOT what I want.

Any and all help is appreciated as always! Thanks!

Comment: check out xp_getfiledetails  and xp_dirtree among others. Sounds like what you are trying to get at.

Comment: One way to do this you can find in this answer I gave [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34843612/243373) on SO. It uses OLE automation. There are other ways, the answer illustrates one of them.

Comment: Another way (out of several others) is from the [SQL#](http://www.sqlsharp.com/features/) library. The function is `GetFileInfo`, sadly it is in the non-free section. Yet another way is to use shell commands and use `xp_cmdshell` to get the results.

Comment: Does the fact that it is a network path and not an attached disk affect the usage of either of those options?

Comment: It also looks like I would likely need to use a cursor to iterate over all the rows of files

Comment: Did the references help you in any way?

Comment: I'm still working on my solution, so when it's finalized, I'll select an answer or ask you to submit yours as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question for completeness...

I was unable to use any of the options provided in the comments on the question, due to limitations in the Production environment where this query needed to be run. Instead, I ran the query to select the desired rows and exported it to a CSV file. I then wrote a quick and dirty Java program (only because it's my most comfortable language and I had similar projects from the past that I could reuse) that took a CSV file as an argument and parsed the CSV and checked each of the files and output a total file size in the console. While it doesn't solve the original question in SQL, it did resolve the problem in this particular case.

Note: If anyone has a SQL solution they can submit as an answer that I can verify as a valid answer, I will switch to that as the accepted answer.