# What is the meaning of "%a" when doing rename in CMD

Tags: cmd

I don't know much about CMD,but when I tried to batch rename files by adding prefix and I looked up google, someone provided with this command 
"for %a in *.* do ren "%a" "00_%a""

I managed to obtain the result I wanted, but I'm just curious as to what "%a" mean. Before this, I tried to add prefix to file names by using just "ren" command but it didn't work...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509652/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-a-cmd-file

Comment: See `help for` or `for /?` in a cmd window or read [ss64.com/nt/for](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Answer (score 0):

The %a is a variable. The value of the variable changes for each iteration of the for loop, in this case the value is a file name because the "in ." means every filename in the current directory. You can learn more about CMD batch language in textbooks or using the basic help built into CMD.