# Defining these batch commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

Over the past few years I've really found Stackoverflow to be very helpful, and decided to create an account - this is my first post.

Example situation - I have a fair few of these images, of different subjects -

```
AAA_BBB_randomDigits_front.jpg
AAA_BBB_randomDigits_left.jpg
AAA_BBB_randomDigits_right.jpg

ZZZ_EEE_randomDigits_front.jpg
ZZZ_EEE_randomDigits_left.jpg
ZZZ_EEE_randomDigits_right.jpg
```

I would like them to all be grouped up in folders as -

```
AAA_BBB_randomDigits\(contains left, front and right)
ZZZ_EEE_randomDigits\(contains left, front and right)
```

The code I currently have works -

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *_*_*_*.*') do (
md "%%a_%%b_%%c" 2>nul
move "%%a_%%b_%%c*" "%%a_%%b_%%c"
)
pause
```

However, I would love it if someone could explain to me -

- What's `%%a?`
- What's `dir /b /a-d` and why do I need it?
- Is it neccessary to have `@echo off` and `pause?`

Thanks guys, I really appreciate it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14509652/5267751

Comment: @user202729 so he isnot allowed to ask a legitimate question? It is a well formatted question and he would like to be part of SO.

Comment: Thanks @GerhardBarnard (I believed you help with the answer below?). I appreciate it.

User202729 - actually, I don't know which documentation you are referring to - if it's easy to get to then that's an oversight on my part - but if you're referring to the default 'descriptions' from batch commands, then I've already read it, and I've also read the link you provided prior to asking. Contrary to your assumptions, I have tried to do some research prior to asking this question, incase this was a repeated question. But it wasn't as helpful to me and my questions, as the answer provided below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For documentation, see *commandname* /? from the prompt.

`dir /b /a-d filemask` performs a directory listing `/b` specifies filenames only - no size, date, header or footer. The `/a-d` excludes directorynames.

You need it to provide the names to the `for /f` command.

`for /f` reads the "filename" in parentheses (it can be a real filename or a single-quoted command (like `dir`) or a double-quoted literal string) and assigns values to the *metavariable* (in this case, `%%a`) according to the specified options (the part in quotes directly following the `/f`).

The `delims` option specifies which set of characters is used for parsing the line of data arriving from the "file" specified. The line is then interpreted as a series of *tokens*, separated by *delimiter-sequences*. By default, `delims` is <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd>. It's common to turn `delims` off entirely using `"...delims="` in which case, there is but one token (the entire line). Note that any characters between `delims=` and `"` are equally-ranking and case-sensitive - it is a `set` of delimiters which *replaces* <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd>, not a `delimiter-string`.

The `tokens` option specifies which tokens are selected, by number, starting at 1. The special token `*` means "the remainder of the line following the highest-number token specified (including any delimiter characters)". By default, `tokens=1`.

`%%a` is a *metavariable*. It is the variable that holds the first token number selected from the `tokens=` list. Each selected token number is assigned to the next *metavariable* name in alphabetical sequence, hence in your example, since you have `tokens=1-3` then `%%a` is the first token, `%%b` the second and `%%c` the third. *Metavariables* are always one letter (some other characters are sometimes used - but numerics are definitely not allowed) and the name is case-sensitive (normally, batch is case-insensitive). `%%a`, `%%A` and `%a%` are all different variables. `%a%` and `%A%` are the *same* variable.

A *metavariable* is only valid within the `for` loop where it was created. When the `for` loop ends, the variable disappears.

`@echo off` simply turns off the command-echoing that batch would otherwise produce (show the command on the console, then execute it). It's used to reduce clutter on the display. When debugging a section of code, it's normal to set `echo` to `on` (`echo on`) and then off again (`echo off`) to show precisely what instructions are being executed. The `@` means "don't report this command to the console"

The `pause` simply waits until a response is received from the keyboard. It's used to allow the display to be read rather than simply continuing directly to the next instruction. It's often used in debugging and also to allow the result of a batch to be held for the user if the batch is executed by using point-click-and-giggle.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard : good spotting. Always get those defaults and the characters-requiring-escapes confused. Hope I've now fixed that once and for all.

Comment: Technically, `/A-D` displays all objects with read-only, hidden, ready for archiving, system, not content indexed, and reparse points which are not directories. As soon as you use `/A`, it effectively considers that all attributes are wanted, you then need to use the not prefix `-` to deselect the unwanted attributes.

Comment: I don't know where to begin - thank you so much for taking the time to explain the code to me! I've searched quite a bit (seemingly not well enough), but what you've provided was super helpful!

The code was put together via 'instinctively' looking at different codes that were on the same topic as what I was trying to achieve. It was mostly tests and trials before I arrived at what worked, but didn't fully understand it until now.

Thank you very much! And thanks Compo - for that extra bit of info :D! You guys rock!

Comment: @RogerTang Now the next step is to decide if this answer solved your question, if it did, you can mark it as correct as this will then be a solved solution and it might assist other users with similar questions in future.

Comment: Awesome! Definitely did, and will do that now :D Thanks @GerhardBarnard!