# running command line from ruby rspec

Tags: ruby, shell, command-line, rspec

I have a spec file with the following code and i run it using rake

```
describe 'Running Reselience test', test_execute: true do     
    it "running deploy build access service and manage" do
       system("for i in {1..3}; do sleep 5; echo $i; done &")
       system("for i in {10..13}; do sleep 5; echo $i; done &")    
    end 
end
```

I am getting the following error in command line when i run the above spec file

```
i was unexpected at this time.
i was unexpected at this time.
```

How do i run the above batch commands without getting the above error?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do i run those batch command without getting an error

Comment: this is not reproducible for me, I can run those `system` commands without issue. What shell are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the https://superuser.com/questions/894475/for-do-command-gives-was-unexpected-at-this-time-when-run-from-command-prompt URL author mentioned

When referencing For loop variable within a batch file you need to double up the percent signs (ie: %%a), **but if you do this when just running the command straight at the prompt it won't work. You need to change them to a single percent sign (%a).**

Also in this URL [single line for statement: %%i 'unexpected at this time'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898088/single-line-for-statement-i-unexpected-at-this-time) 
The author mentioned using a single percent sign

I am using the Linux OS (so can't test your scenario)  but as per the below links you need to change your command syntax

URL https://www.windows-commandline.com/windows-for-loop-examples/

URL [DOS FOR loop on range through command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577492/dos-for-loop-on-range-through-command-line)

URL https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html

For example

```
for %i in (user1 user2 user3 user4 user5 user6) do net user /delete %i
```

so in your case

```
FOR /l %i in (1,1,3) DO sleep 5 & echo %i
```

Comment: Thanks @amit , so that progressed a step but now I am getting {1..3}  was unexpected at this time

Comment: @AutomateFr33k, I am using the Linux OS (so can't test your scenario)  but as per the below links you need to change your command syntax. I have modified above mentioned answer post